# How to label a point on the axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I want label a point(0.5066,-5.4) on the x axis, I try to use codes `\node[label={180:{($\varepsilon_{cor}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};` It shows the up half of the labe. How can I label a point on the axis and make it under the axis like tick,but not change the tick?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$\varepsilon$ /\si{\volt}},
            ylabel={$\lg \vert I \vert$},
            axis lines = box,
            xmin=0.18, xmax=0.82,
            ymin=-5.4, ymax=-2.9,
            xtick={0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8},
            ytick={-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,]
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.2208 ,-3.05061)
            (0.2809 ,-3.1549 )
            (0.3309 ,-3.26761)
            (0.3709 ,-3.38722)
            (0.4008 ,-3.49485)
            (0.4208 ,-3.58503)
            (0.4309 ,-3.63827)
            (0.4408 ,-3.69897)
            (0.4508 ,-3.76955)
            (0.4609 ,-3.85387)
            (0.4708 ,-3.95861)
            (0.4759 ,-4.04576)
            (0.4808 ,-4.09691)
            (0.4858 ,-4.22185)
            (0.4909 ,-4.30103)
            (0.4958 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4978 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4998 ,-4.69897)
            (0.5019 ,-5      )
            (0.5039 ,-5      )
            (0.5063 ,-5.41   )}; 
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.5066 ,-5.41   )  
            (0.5101 ,-5      )  
            (0.5121 ,-5      )  
            (0.5141 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.5161 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.521  ,-4.39794)  
            (0.526  ,-4.30103)  
            (0.5311 ,-4.1549 )  
            (0.536  ,-4.09691)  
            (0.5411 ,-4      )  
            (0.5511 ,-3.88606)  
            (0.5611 ,-3.79588)  
            (0.5711 ,-3.72125)  
            (0.5811 ,-3.67778)  
            (0.5911 ,-3.61979)  
            (0.611  ,-3.52288)  
            (0.6412 ,-3.40894)  
            (0.6811 ,-3.30103)  
            (0.7311 ,-3.19382)  
            (0.7911 ,-3.09691)}; 
            \node[label={180:{($\varepsilon_{cor}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yshift` to shift the label. The node with the label becomes:

```
\node[label={[yshift=2ex]180:{($\varepsilon_{cor}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};
```

Leaving the rest as it is now, the result is:

[image]

**EDIT**

Since it's been requested by the OP, I include another solution. To position the label on the right of the tick you should specify `label={[right,yshift...`.

I took the liberty of manually align it

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$\varepsilon$ /\si{\volt}},
            ylabel={$\lg \vert I \vert$},
            axis lines = box,
            xmin=0.18, xmax=0.82,
            ymin=-5.4, ymax=-2.9,
            xtick={0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8},
            ytick={-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,]
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.2208 ,-3.05061)
            (0.2809 ,-3.1549 )
            (0.3309 ,-3.26761)
            (0.3709 ,-3.38722)
            (0.4008 ,-3.49485)
            (0.4208 ,-3.58503)
            (0.4309 ,-3.63827)
            (0.4408 ,-3.69897)
            (0.4508 ,-3.76955)
            (0.4609 ,-3.85387)
            (0.4708 ,-3.95861)
            (0.4759 ,-4.04576)
            (0.4808 ,-4.09691)
            (0.4858 ,-4.22185)
            (0.4909 ,-4.30103)
            (0.4958 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4978 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4998 ,-4.69897)
            (0.5019 ,-5      )
            (0.5039 ,-5      )
            (0.5063 ,-5.41   )}; 
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.5066 ,-5.41   )  
            (0.5101 ,-5      )  
            (0.5121 ,-5      )  
            (0.5141 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.5161 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.521  ,-4.39794)  
            (0.526  ,-4.30103)  
            (0.5311 ,-4.1549 )  
            (0.536  ,-4.09691)  
            (0.5411 ,-4      )  
            (0.5511 ,-3.88606)  
            (0.5611 ,-3.79588)  
            (0.5711 ,-3.72125)  
            (0.5811 ,-3.67778)  
            (0.5911 ,-3.61979)  
            (0.611  ,-3.52288)  
            (0.6412 ,-3.40894)  
            (0.6811 ,-3.30103)  
            (0.7311 ,-3.19382)  
            (0.7911 ,-3.09691)}; 
            \node[label={[right,yshift=2.1ex,xshift=0.3em]180:{($\varepsilon_{\mathrm{cor}})=0.5066$}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

**EDIT2**

I repositioned the label on the axis.

The core part is:

```
extra x ticks={0.5066},
        extra x tick labels={$\varepsilon_{\mathrm{cor}} ({\scriptstyle 0.5066})$},
```

Also, I kind of corrected the axis tick:

```
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};
```

The code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$\varepsilon$ /\si{\volt}},
            ylabel={$\lg \vert I \vert$},
            axis lines = box,
            xmin=0.18, xmax=0.82,
            ymin=-5.4, ymax=-2.9,
            xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8},
            ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            extra x ticks={0.5066},
            extra x tick labels={$\varepsilon_{\mathrm{cor}} ({\scriptstyle 0.5066})$},
            grid style=dashed,]
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.2208 ,-3.05061)
            (0.2809 ,-3.1549 )
            (0.3309 ,-3.26761)
            (0.3709 ,-3.38722)
            (0.4008 ,-3.49485)
            (0.4208 ,-3.58503)
            (0.4309 ,-3.63827)
            (0.4408 ,-3.69897)
            (0.4508 ,-3.76955)
            (0.4609 ,-3.85387)
            (0.4708 ,-3.95861)
            (0.4759 ,-4.04576)
            (0.4808 ,-4.09691)
            (0.4858 ,-4.22185)
            (0.4909 ,-4.30103)
            (0.4958 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4978 ,-4.52288)
            (0.4998 ,-4.69897)
            (0.5019 ,-5      )
            (0.5039 ,-5      )
            (0.5063 ,-5.41   )}; 
        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=*, mark size=1.5,
            ]
            coordinates {
            (0.5066 ,-5.41   )  
            (0.5101 ,-5      )  
            (0.5121 ,-5      )  
            (0.5141 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.5161 ,-4.69897)  
            (0.521  ,-4.39794)  
            (0.526  ,-4.30103)  
            (0.5311 ,-4.1549 )  
            (0.536  ,-4.09691)  
            (0.5411 ,-4      )  
            (0.5511 ,-3.88606)  
            (0.5611 ,-3.79588)  
            (0.5711 ,-3.72125)  
            (0.5811 ,-3.67778)  
            (0.5911 ,-3.61979)  
            (0.611  ,-3.52288)  
            (0.6412 ,-3.40894)  
            (0.6811 ,-3.30103)  
            (0.7311 ,-3.19382)  
            (0.7911 ,-3.09691)}; 
                       \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:0.5066,-5.4) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

And here is the result

[image]

Basically:

- I reduced the ticks on both axis (you can do as you wish)
- I provided an extra tick on the x axis, with `extra x ticks`
- I provided a label for the extra tick (you may want fine-tuning the style, e.g. with a `\small` or revising the numbers)
- I removed the label on the plot, being redundant
- I reduced the `inner sep` of the single tick on the axis to `1.5pt` and it may require fine tuning

I think you can pick up from here.

Comment: How can I place the label out of the coordinate box, just between the tick 0.5 and 0.6 and mark it with $\varepsilon_{cor}=0.5066$ without the half point on the x axis?

Comment: to position you have `label={[right,yshift=2ex]`

Comment: @ChaoSong I'm editing the answer

Comment: @ChaoSong something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any method to place it **under the x axis**, looks like a tick value? And changing the half point in(0.5066,-5.4) to whole point or just make it disappear?

Comment: @ChaoSong working on it, at least on the axis part

Comment: @ChaoSong I fine tuned it. I think I cannot do much more than that, other than point you to the docs!